Powershell: Invoke-Webrequest using secure string
Here is my question, I can't find anything online nor will ai help me (Might be my fault tho)
So I want to use some Invoke-Webrequest cmdlts, but I first have to login to the website.
I tried it with PLAIN Credentials, everything is working like expected. But now I have to get the script working with a Secure String password (and a SecretVault for stored Creds but thats not the Problem right now)
The Webpage is reading the Secure String literal so it obviously wont accept my pw.

Is there a way to format the String so im able to correctly pass it to the webpage?
I know i can make it plain but thats obviously not what i want.
Maybe there is a compromise?

The request has to be POST
Or maybe there is even a way to properly imbed the Secure String so its readable for the webpage(?)
#This is not the acutal script im working on but a mini version on a test site, the $dbForm.Action is probably not working but it doesnt matter here

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://keepass.info/help/kb/testform.html" -SessionVariable ses
$dbForm = $r.Forms.Fields

$dbForm["LoginFormUser"] = "testuser"

#Note that i want this to be a Secure String:
#But as of right now this only works plain

$password = "PlainPW"

$dbForm["pwd"] = $password

$r1 = Invoke-WebRequest -uri ("https://keepass.info/help/kb/testform.html" + $dbForm.Action) -WebSession $ses -UseBasicParsing -Method Post -Body $dbForm


To encrypt your plain password to a secure string and then convert the secure string to an encrypted string you could do something like the following:
$encryptedPW = 'PlainPW' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText | ConvertFrom-SecureString

In the above, 'PlainPW' is your password in cleartext, same as you used in your example.
If you then need to decrypt the above $encryptedPW, you could use the following:
$clearPW = $encryptedPW | ConvertTo-SecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText

Could you clarify further why you would want to do this? It may help future readers understand the use case.
Please note that a Powershell SecureString is specific to a user and machine. The resulting [System.Security.SecureString] is not portable.
